# Emotion JS: How to apply styles to child when hover parent?

Tags: css, emotion

Seems like this question has been asked and answered many different ways, but the answers I've seen either don't apply to Emotion or the Emotion-related answered haven't worked for me. I'm on @emtion/core@10.0.28 and @emtion/styled@10.0.27.

Essentially I want to apply styles to a child component when the parent is hovered/active/focused. The parent is a button and the child is an optional icon. The following styles are added to the (parent) button via the `styled` syntax.

```
const iconWrapperStyles = (props) => {
  return css`
    ${props.IconWrapper} {
      width: ${iconSizeMedium};
      height: ${iconSizeMedium};
      margin-left: ${spacingSizeSmall};
      color: ${textColor};
      fill: ${textColor};
      background: ${backgroundColor};
      border-color: ${borderColor};
    }

    &:hover:not(:disabled),
    &:focus:not(:disabled),
    &:active:not(:disabled) ${props.IconWrapper} {
      outline: none;
      color: ${textColorHover};
      fill: ${textColorHover};
      background: ${backgroundColorHover};
      border-color: ${borderColorHover};
    }
  `;
};
```

The first block of styles is successfully applied. Therefore, at first blush, the button and child icon appear properly styled. However, when you hover/focus/make active the button, the icon does not change. I've tried the implementation above, along with `... + ${IconWrapper}` and `... & ${IconWrapper}`; all three fail for me. [Official docs](https://emotion.sh/docs/nested) indicate that the `&` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the JS framework, the following should always work.

```css
button {
  background: darkblue;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

button:hover i {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<button>
  <i class='icon-edit'></i> Click to edit
</button>
```

In your case, that becomes

```js
   ${props.IconWrapper} {
     width: ${iconSizeMedium};
     height: ${iconSizeMedium};
     margin-left: ${spacingSizeSmall};
     color: ${textColor};
     fill: ${textColor};
     background: ${backgroundColor};
     border-color: ${borderColor};
   }

   &:hover:not(:disabled) ${props.IconWrapper},
   &:focus:not(:disabled) ${props.IconWrapper},
   &:active:not(:disabled) ${props.IconWrapper} {
     outline: none;
     color: ${textColorHover};
     fill: ${textColorHover};
     background: ${backgroundColorHover};
     border-color: ${borderColorHover};
   }
```

Comment: This answer is not quite right, but it did give me the clue! Your solution is off because IconWrapper is not the parent, so the hover etc styles you've declared are localized to IconWrapper only, which was my initial problem. Please the answer I'll add shortly.

Comment: Okay cool, happy to help! I'll update my answer to match it then

Answer (score 0):

I failed because my CSS is weak. Comma-separated CSS decorators do not iterate against the finally-declared element.

From this...

```
&:hover:not(:disabled),
&:focus:not(:disabled),
&:active:not(:disabled) ${props.IconWrapper} {
  outline: none;
  color: ${textColorHover};
  fill: ${textColorHover};
  background: ${backgroundColorHover};
  border-color: ${borderColorHover};
}
```

To this...

```
&:hover:not(:disabled) ${props.IconWrapper}, // include child el
&:focus:not(:disabled) ${props.IconWrapper}, // include child el
&:active:not(:disabled) ${props.IconWrapper} {
  outline: none;
  color: ${textColorHover};
  fill: ${textColorHover};
  background: ${backgroundColorHover};
  border-color: ${borderColorHover};
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rubenhelsloot for putting me on the right track